# Free memory is occupied

Tags: linux

I have the free memory getting filled up pretty fast, It seems like the ec2-user is running a script and the process moves to the sleep state and starts to occupy memory but never frees up.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.5G        6.6G        645M        9.9M        288M        683M
Low:           7.5G        6.9G        645M
High:            0B          0B          0B
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

this is the current free memory i have, when i ran the `ps-aux --sort -pmem` to check the process occupying the memory i could see

```
signalf+ 21914  1.1  0.8 151784 63232 ?        Ssl  13:06   0:44 /usr/bin/signalfx-agent
signalf+ 21939  1.3  0.5 746460 45500 ?        Sl   13:07   0:51 /usr/lib/signalfx-agent/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/signalfx-agent/bin/collectd -f -C /var/run/signalfx-agent/collectd/global/collectd.conf
root      1447  0.0  0.5 345428 44988 ?        Ss    2020  59:37 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
ec2-user  8355  0.0  0.3 335192 30320 ?        S    14:04   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  8682  0.0  0.3 335176 30200 ?        S    14:05   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  7774  0.0  0.3 335168 30180 ?        S    14:02   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  9126  0.0  0.3 335168 30152 ?        S    14:06   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  9625  0.0  0.3 335180 30136 ?        S    14:08   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  9417  0.0  0.3 335180 30124 ?        S    14:07   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  9939  0.1  0.3 335172 30116 ?        S    14:09   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  7542  0.0  0.3 335176 30100 ?        S    14:01   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  8147  0.0  0.3 335172 30092 ?        S    14:03   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user 10159  0.2  0.3 335164 30032 ?        S    14:10   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
root     21507  0.0  0.3 298328 29000 ?        S     2020 119:45 /sbin/cmd_daemon
ec2-user  6458  0.0  0.3 335420 27428 ?        S    14:00   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  3976  0.0  0.3 338024 27212 ?        S    10:31   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  4480  0.0  0.3 338148 26992 ?        S    10:33   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user 10745  0.5  0.3 332600 26972 ?        S    14:11   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user 31230  0.0  0.3 335592 25308 ?        S    10:11   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user 17154  0.0  0.3 335572 25192 ?        S    09:03   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  5979  0.0  0.3 335432 24840 ?        S    13:58   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  3599  0.0  0.3 335424 24836 ?        S    13:50   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  4610  0.0  0.3 335420 24828 ?        S    13:53   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
ec2-user  5103  0.0  0.3 335420 24792 ?        S    13:55   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/CPM.py
```

this is repeatedly occupying and i'm not sure if i should kill them or do anything else. As per my understanding if the script is successful it should free up the memory space but does this mean the script runs but fails to complete and moves into sleep state. And the free memory keeps increasing gradually. I'm new to this, So any help would be very much useful.

Comment: What system is this on? Who is `ec2-user`? Anyway, seems off-topic for SO as not about programming.

Comment: If the script has been written "in house" find out who wrote the script and get their input.